# Java: how to draw an SVG file in a PDF file?

Tags: java, pdf, svg, pdfbox

Our app is supposed to typeset PDF bills with bar codes (in SVG format) embedded in them. I tried to find some advice on internet, yet did not find anything that simply works..

Q: could you provided a code snippet that shows how to go around that issue?

PS: In the snippet, you can safely assume that we have figured out all the XML in the SVG bar codes.

Comment: You could try to use https://github.com/rototor/pdfbox-graphics2d  in combination with Apache Batik. (No I can't provide code) But the better solution would be to draw directly. I use ZXIng and then draw a 1x1 rectangle for every dot.

Comment: You should be able to convert SVG to PDF using a HTML to PDF converter (there are various server side options out there). Then it would be a matter of applying/inserting the new PDF page content (you got from HTML to PDF) to the existing target PDF page.